# Get message correlation id in ProcessErrorAsync

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an Azure Service Bus message consumer class, using queues.

I want to add the correlation id of the message to the logs I write. This is easily done in the Service Bus Processor's `ProcessMessagesAsync` method as I get the message as a parameter. But, I could not find a way to get the correlation id in the `ProcessErrorAsync` method.

The consuming service is registered as a singleton service in an ASP.NET Core app. I thought about using a local variable to store the correlation id when the message processing starts in the `ProcessMessagesAsync` method, and use that value in the `ProcessErrorAsync` method as well.

First question, is there a way to get the correlation id in the `ProcessErrorAsync` method?

Second question, is the local variable option feasible, or will it have issues if more then 1 concurrent call is handled at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to correlate a specific message with an invocation of the `ProcessErrorAsync` handler.  The handler is invoked for a number of reasons, many of which are not associated with a message.

If there are actions that you'd like to take on a message if processing fails, it is recommended that you include a `try/catch` block in your `ProcessMessagesAsync` handler code to detect the processing error and perform those actions.